# angularJs TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a small AngularJs app like so:

```
 // html

 <div ng-repeat="project in projects">
     <h3>{{ project.id }}</h3>
     <h3>{{ project.title }}</h3>
      <div ng-repeat="task in project.tasks">
          <h4>{{ task.id }}. {{ task.title }}</h4>
          <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="showEditTask=true">Edit Task</button>
          <div class="box row animate-show-hide" ng-show="showEditTask">

              <h2>Create a New Task</h2>
              <form name="newTaskForm" class="form-horizontal">
                  Title: <br />
                  <input ng-model="new_task.title" type="text" id="title" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" required /><br />

                  Project: <br />
                  <select ng-model="new_task.project" ng-options="project.title for project in projects" class="form-control"></select><br>
              </form>

                  <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="createTask(new_task)" ng-disabled="!newTaskForm.title.$valid">create</button>
          </div>
      </div>
 </div>


  // app.js

  concernsApp.factory('ConcernService', function ($http, $q) {

    ...

    update: function (obj_url, obj) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        console.log(obj)
        $http({method: 'POST',
            url: api_url + obj_url + obj.id + '/',
            data: obj}).
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                defer.resolve(data);
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                defer.reject(status);
            });
        return defer.promise;
     },
   });


 concernsApp.controller('ProjectsCtrl', function ($scope, $http, ConcernService) {

    $scope.updateTask = function(obj) {
        ConcernService.update('tasks/', obj).then(function(){
        ...
    }
 });
```

The problem is with updating a task and leaving the parent project as is. If I change the parent project, it all works fine. If I use the same parent project then I get:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

I'm not entirely sure what is happening here.

### Edit

So, I can solve the problem like this:

```
$scope.updateTask = function(obj) {
    parentProject = {'id': obj.project.id};
    obj.project = parentProject;
    ConcernService.update('tasks/', obj).then(function(){
        ...
    });
};
```

This works as I only actually need the `task.project.id` to update the object. I *think* the problem is due to that fact that the task references a parent project, which in turn references the child tasks etc. I'm not entirely sure about this tough.

However, this solution seems a little hacky to me and I would love to see a better solution.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Somewhere you are trying to convert an object to JSON, and that has a circular reference in it, meaning something like this:

```
var myObj = new Object();
myObject.reference = myObj;
```

Now trying to convert this to JSON will fail, and produce your error.

Looking at the your edited post, your data structure is something like this:

```
task.parent -> {project}

project.tasks -> [{task1},{task2},...]
```

This is supposed to model the relation "project has multiple tasks" and "task belongs to a project".

Now this can obviously not be converted to json format, due to circular referencing.

For the data structure, why not go with:

```
project = { "id": 42,
            "tasks": [123, 124, 127, ... ],
          }

task = { "id": 123,
         "idproject": 42,
            ...
       }
```

Whenever you have to show the relationships in your angularjs app, you could go with filters. If you want to show what belongs to a project, filter all tasks by projectid.

Or retrieve only the required data from your backend on the fly, by requesting what tasks the backend has for a specific project id.

That is one way to do it. Of course, having the backend accept appropriate update requests would be working just as well, e.g. updating a project would require the project id, and an array of task ids.

Comment: hmmm. Well I'm not using JSON.stringify in my code. It seems to fail at the `ConcernService.update` method.

Comment: The interesting thing is that it all works when I change the project in the select field. So I know there is a circular reference on  `new_task.project` but I'm unsure where it is.

Comment: If you have Chrome Browser, you can use the developer tools to debug the javascript, the same works with Firebug addon in Mozilla. You can inspect the object in your code while its running, and compare to working case with the problem case.

Comment: It is going to be the $http service doing the json conversion, but that probably doesnt help as its already apparent the problem is surfacing there.

Comment: Please see my edit for a solution which works but seems a little ugly :/

Comment: You could probably rework your data structure, or change the parameter set that the backend requires for the updates.