# Angular Directive "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I get this problem since long time, but I just ignored it so far. This is working code:

```
 <div ng-show="!cs.isEditing">{{cs.refCompound.name}}</div><select ng-show="cs.isEditing" ng-model="cs.refCompound" ng-options="g.name for g in method.refCompoundList"><option value=""></option></select>
```

Now, I'm trying to convert this into a directive as:

```
app.directive('msSelectCell', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            name: '=',
            isEditing: '=',
            isHidden: '=',
            options: '=',
            model: '='
        },
        template: 
            '<div>' +
            '    <div ng-hide="!isHidden" style="background-color: lightgrey">&nbsp;</div>' +
            '    <div ng-show="!isEditing && !isHidden">{{name}}</div>' +
            '    <select class="select-input"  ng-show="isEditing && !isHidden" ng-model="model" ng-options="g.name || g for g in options"><option value=""></option></select>' +
            '</div>'
    }
});
```

This directive is working fine for all other cases, except one like this:

```
<ms-select-cell name="cs.refCompound.name" is-editing="cs.isEditing" options="method.refCompoundList" model="cs.refCompound" is-hidden="cs.useAsRtRef"/>
```

As I figured out, it is because 'refCompoundList' is an extended property of method as defined:

```
    Object.defineProperty(Method.prototype, 'refCompoundList', {
        get: function () {
            var list = [];
            this.compoundSettings.forEach(function (cs) {
                if (cs.useAsRtRef)
                    list.push(cs.compound);
            });
            return list;
        }
    });
```

So, I don't understand why method.refCompound is working fine outside the directive, but I got this error when it is passed into a directive only?

UPDATE: Okay, I tried to create a plunker at [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/A9jG3LRIy7PODQdX443S?p=preview), but it's not fully working as I desire. I need to make the select options to use an extended property that is dynamically populated, and I don't know how to do it in plunker. Hope somebody can fix it for me. It's now using the sexes array from scope which is not a problem.

Comment: Please post plunk with code (or similar)

Comment: maybe, it help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20275455/angular-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json