# Angular: What's wrong with this directive?

Tags: angularjs, filter, directive

Basically, I want to use the filteredList from repeat in a directive as follows:

```
  <tr ng-repeat="emp in (filteredList = (data.employees | filter:searchString))">
  ...

  <ms-pager items="filteredList" skip-items="skipItems"></ms-pager>
```

I created a plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Yrw4CVhKJUFBkQJZNxz4?p=preview) to illustrate the problem. When you enter a search string, e.g. J, the filter works fine, but I got the following error:

> Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

As I figured, this is because I passed filteredList to my ms-pager directive. If I don't use this directive, everything works fine. So, is this a bug in directive, or a limitation in directive, or my code error?

Note that, the directive works, it just bothers me that so many errors showing up in browser's console.

Comment: I have a hunch your `digest()` issue is due to the assignment of `filteredList` in the `ng-repeat`. Nonetheless, I hacked up an alternative solution in which you watch `searchString` in your controller, and then use `$filter` to do the filtering inside the controller, instead of the `ng-repeat` expression. Here you go - http://plnkr.co/edit/sSgtQQEqyU1HrWTlzKj3?p=preview

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggested workaround. Actually, I already got a workaround, but the issue really bothers me because I suspect I had similar issues somewhere else (please see my other question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22341668/angular-directive-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json) and I want to see if there is a proper fix.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the () around

```
data.employees | filter:searchString

(filteredList = data.employees | filter:searchString)
```

See [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/n4m5henVLIeCTzivB7b1?p=preview)

I also noticed you are not passing any data into "skipItems"

Comment: removing the parentheses will change the function of the directive: It doesn't show the length of the filteredList any more. This is the main point of the directive.

Comment: I missed that, Let me retake a look.

Comment: This issue with the length has to do with your watch not triggering on the item.length object in your directive. There were two issues here. One with the 10 $digest the (), Second is the watch not triggering on the item.length.

Comment: Hi, tmc, thank you very much for your effort, but it doesn't fix my problem. I really need to pass filteredList to the directive because I need to do something else too. The directive shown in this question is just a stripped down version to illustrate the problem. Also, I don't see any difference by removing the parentheses.

Comment: Are you trying to do this? This problem fixes the issue with filtered list(items.length) not updating in the directive. http://plnkr.co/edit/BJFTm9oyK4svvF3XP73f?p=preview

Comment: It works, but the same problem still occurs (hit F12 to see it in browser's console). Please note that the original directive works, it's the errors in console that bothers me.